# Concurrent POST requests w/ attachment Python

Tags: python, concurrency, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a server which waits for a request containing a pictures:

```
@app.route("/uploader_ios", methods=['POST'])
def upload_file_ios():
    imagefile = request.files['imagefile']
```

I can submit a post request quite easily using requests in python like so:

```
url = "<myserver>/uploader_ios"
files = {'imagefile': open(fname, 'rb')}
%time requests.post(url, files=files).json()  # 2.77s
```

However, what I would like to do is submit 1000 or perhaps 100,000 requests at the same time. I wanted to try to do this using asyncio because I have been able to use this for get requests without a problem. However I can't see to create a valid post request that the server accepts.

My attempt is below:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import json

# Testing with small amount
concurrent = 2
url_list = ['<myserver>/uploader_ios'] * 10

def handle_req(data):
    return json.loads(data)['English']

def chunked_http_client(num_chunks, s):
    # Use semaphore to limit number of requests
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(num_chunks)
    @asyncio.coroutine
    # Return co-routine that will work asynchronously and respect
    # locking of semaphore

    def http_get(url):
        nonlocal semaphore
        with (yield from semaphore):

            # Attach files
            files = aiohttp.FormData()
            files.add_field('imagefile', open(fname, 'rb'))

            response = yield from s.request('post', url, data=files)
            print(response)

            body = yield from response.content.read()
            yield from response.wait_for_close()
        return body
    return http_get

def run_experiment(urls, _session):
    http_client = chunked_http_client(num_chunks=concurrent, s=_session)

    # http_client returns futures, save all the futures to a list
    tasks = [http_client(url) for url in urls]

    dfs_route = []

    # wait for futures to be ready then iterate over them
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        data = yield from future
        try:
            out = handle_req(data)
            dfs_route.append(out)
        except Exception as err:
            print("Error {0}".format(err))
    return dfs_route

with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:  # We create a persistent connection
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    calc_routes = loop.run_until_complete(run_experiment(url_list, session))
```

The issue is that the response I get is:

```
.../uploader_ios) [400 BAD REQUEST]>
```

I am assuming this is because I am not correctly attaching the image-file

Comment: My guess is that the `data` argument is for the body of the POST. There's probably a `files` argument for files.

Comment: @dirn Ah so server expects request.files.imagefile but gets request.data.imagefile. I had a re-read of the [doc](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) and it seems that adding them as 'data' is the only way. I wonder if it's possible to change the name of data to files before sending

Comment: Like I said, it was just a guess. Your best bet is to check the logs on the server (or run it in debug mode if `app` supports such a thing) to see what is actually triggering the 400 error.